# How to create a mesh dynamically In unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dynamic, mesh

I have vertex that have a color value.

I'd like to make a mesh using vertex with the same color values.

[image]

This picture is an example.

I took pictures with my Android Phone, and I did image segmentation on the object

So I got a color value corresponding to the coordinate value.

I succeeded in just making textures. please check the image.
[image]

But I want a mesh object.

Below is making texture code.

```
var pixel = await this.segmentation.SegmentAsync(rotated, scaled.width, scaled.height);
// int pixel[][];                   // image segmentation using tensorflow

Color transparentColor = new Color32(255, 255, 255, 0);  // transparent
for (int y = 0; y < texture.height; y++)
{
      for (int x = 0; x < texture.width; x++)
      {
             int class_output = pixel[y][x];   

              texture.SetPixel(x, y, pixel[y][x] == 0 ? transparentColor : colors[class_output]);
      }
}
texture.Apply();
```

How can I make a mesh object?

Comment: With Unity3D Mesh class... https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html

Comment: if you have the outline, the process you are looking for is called triangulation (if 2d is ok)

Comment: Apparently you are using ARCore. You can use extracted points to create your meshes as @Dave mentioned. However, i highly doubt that you get a proper mesh at the end of this procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Set a prefab with a MeshFilter and a MeshRenderer.

2- Variables inside the script that you will need to fill.

```
// This first list contains every vertex of the mesh that we are going to render
public List<Vector3> newVertices = new List<Vector3>();

// The triangles tell Unity how to build each section of the mesh joining
// the vertices
public List<int> newTriangles = new List<int>();

// The UV list is unimportant right now but it tells Unity how the texture is
// aligned on each polygon
public List<Vector2> newUV = new List<Vector2>();


// A mesh is made up of the vertices, triangles and UVs we are going to define,
// after we make them up we'll save them as this mesh
private Mesh mesh;
```

3- Initialize the mesh

```
void Start () {

  mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh;

  float x = transform.position.x;
  float y = transform.position.y;
  float z = transform.position.z;

  newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y  , z ));
  newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 1 , y  , z ));
  newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x + 1 , y-1 , z ));
  newVertices.Add( new Vector3 (x  , y-1 , z ));

  newTriangles.Add(0);
  newTriangles.Add(1);
  newTriangles.Add(3);
  newTriangles.Add(1);
  newTriangles.Add(2);
  newTriangles.Add(3);

  newUV.Add(new Vector2 (tUnit * tStone.x, tUnit * tStone.y + tUnit));
  newUV.Add(new Vector2 (tUnit * tStone.x + tUnit, tUnit * tStone.y + tUnit));
  newUV.Add(new Vector2 (tUnit * tStone.x + tUnit, tUnit * tStone.y));
  newUV.Add(new Vector2 (tUnit * tStone.x, tUnit * tStone.y));

  mesh.Clear ();
  mesh.vertices = newVertices.ToArray();
  mesh.triangles = newTriangles.ToArray();
  mesh.uv = newUV.ToArray(); // add this line to the code here
  mesh.Optimize ();
  mesh.RecalculateNormals ();
 }
```

This code will draw a square at the position of the prefab, if you keep adding vertices you can generate a more complex mesh.

The source of information is a tutorial to generate mensh for a terrain like minecrat, check the [link](http://studentgamedev.blogspot.com/2013/08/unity-voxel-tutorial-part-1-generating.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

The answer which has been selected best is, in my opinion, faulty for four reasons. First, it is deprecated. Second, it is more complex than necessary. Third, it offers little explanation, and finally, it is mostly just a copy from someone else's blog post. For that reason, I offer a new suggestion. For more info, [view the documentation here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class meshmaker : MonoBehaviour {

    Mesh mesh;
    MeshFilter meshFilter;
    Vector3[] newVertices;
    int[] newTriangles;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //First, we create an array of vector3's. Each vector3 will 
        //represent one vertex in our mesh. Our shape will be a half 
        //cube (probably the simplest 3D shape we can make.

        newVertices = new Vector3[4];

        newVertices [0] = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        newVertices [1] = new Vector3 (1, 0, 0);
        newVertices [2] = new Vector3 (0, 1, 0);
        newVertices [3] = new Vector3 (0, 0, 1);

        //Next, we create an array of integers which will represent 
        //triangles. Triangles are built by taking integers in groups of 
        //three, with each integer representing a vertex from our array of 
        //vertices. Note that the integers are in a certain order. The order 
        //of integers determines the normal of the triangle. In this case, 
        //connecting 021 faces the triangle out, while 012 faces the 
        //triangle in.

        newTriangles = new int[12];

        newTriangles[0] = 0;
        newTriangles[1] = 2;
        newTriangles[2] = 1;

        newTriangles[3] = 0;
        newTriangles[4] = 1;
        newTriangles[5] = 3;

        newTriangles[6] = 0;
        newTriangles[7] = 3;
        newTriangles[8] = 2;

        newTriangles[9] = 1;
        newTriangles[10] = 2;
        newTriangles[11] = 3;


        //We instantiate our mesh object and attach it to our mesh filter
        mesh = new Mesh ();
        meshFilter = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
        meshFilter.mesh = mesh;


        //We assign our vertices and triangles to the mesh.
        mesh.vertices = newVertices;
        mesh.triangles = newTriangles;

}
```

Ta da! Your very own half-cube.

Comment: What about that other answer is deprecated? As far as I can tell they're basically using the same method as you, but wit ha few extra method calls...

Comment: Can I be honest here? I'm rarely on this site, and I answered this long enough ago that I don't even remember answering it. Maybe I'm wrong to say it is deprecated. I probably wouldn't have said it though if I didn't have a reason. Was their answer edited since then? Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Honestly is always good. There aren't any edits, but who knows if the selected answer changed. Just making sure I didn't miss something.